GL_INVALID_OPERATION Error and Issues with Fragment Shader Outputs
I am currently developing a custom extension for the Autodesk Viewer, and I'm encountering a problem when trying to change the color of specific parts of the model.
When attempting to change fragment colors using THREE.MeshPhongMaterial in my custom extension, The object identification is fine, but an error occurs in the material representation and the object becomes transparent, resulting in the following error in the browser console:
GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Active draw buffers with missing fragment shader outputs.
I read these post before i post this question.
1
2
I would appreciate any advice on what this error means and the steps I can take to resolve it.
My javascript is below:
class ChangeColorCustom extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
        this._colorPickerId = this.guid();
        this.addCSS();
    }

    addCSS() {
        const link = $('<link/>', {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            type: 'text/css',
            href: '/extensions/ChangeColorCustom/contents/main.css'
        });
        link.appendTo('head');
    }

    load() {
        this.viewer.addEventListener(
            Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
            this.onItemSelected.bind(this)
        );

        this.createUI();

        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        console.log("ChangeColorCustom unloaded");
        this.viewer.removeEventListener(
            Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
            this.onItemSelected
        );
        $(`#${this._colorPickerId}-container`).remove();
        return true;
    }

    createUI() {
        const container = this.viewer.container;

        if (container) {
            const htmlString = `
            <div id="${this._colorPickerId}-container" style="position: absolute; right: 25%; top: 5%; z-index: 100;">
                <input type="text" id="${this._colorPickerId}-DBIdInput" placeholder="Enter DBID">
                <input type="range" id="${this._colorPickerId}-opacitySlider" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1">
                <button id="${this._colorPickerId}-applyColorButton">Apply Color</button>
                <button id="${this._colorPickerId}-resetButton">Reset Color</button>
            </div>
        `;
            container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);

            // Apply color
            $(`#${this._colorPickerId}-applyColorButton`).click(() => {
                const dbId = parseInt($(`#${this._colorPickerId}-DBIdInput`).val(), 10);
                const opacity = parseFloat($(`#${this._colorPickerId}-opacitySlider`).val());
                if (!isNaN(dbId)) {
                    // set the color to `#ffffff`
                    const fixedColor = new THREE.Color("#ffffff");
                    this.changeColor(dbId, fixedColor, opacity);
                }
            });

            // reset button
            $(`#${this._colorPickerId}-resetButton`).click(() => {
                const dbId = parseInt($(`#${this._colorPickerId}-DBIdInput`).val(), 10);
                if (!isNaN(dbId)) {
                    this.resetColor(dbId);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    changeColor(dbId, color, opacity) {
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: color,
            transparent: true,
            opacity: opacity
        });

        material.colorWrite = true;

        const instanceTree = this.viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
        instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, (fragId) => {
            const proxy = this.viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(this.viewer.model, fragId);
            proxy.setMaterial(material);
            proxy.updateAnimTransform();
        }, true);

        this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);
    }

    resetColor(dbId) {
        // Reset to the default material or reset logic here.
    }

    guid() {
        const d = new Date().getTime();
        return 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, (c) => {
            const r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
            return (c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16);
        });
    }

    onItemSelected(event) {
        if (event.dbIdArray.length > 0) {
            const dbId = event.dbIdArray[0];
            this.viewer.getProperties(dbId, (props) => {
                $(`#${this._colorPickerId}-DBIdInput`).val(props.externalId || props.dbId);
            }, (error) => {
                console.error('Error getting properties:', error);
            });
        }
    }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
    'ChangeColorCustom',
    ChangeColorCustom
);


Thank you in advance for your help.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

If you're simply trying to apply a custom color to selected elements in the scene, I would suggest using the standard viewer.setThemingColor method.
Creating custom three.js materials/shaders is also possible in the APS Viewer, however it is a much more involved process since the shaders must always be adjusted for the viewer rendering pipeline.
